# What's the proper way to combine jQuery modal dialogs and ASP.net server side events?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I want to do this simple thing in a ASP.Net application:

I have a button in the the form and which when clicked I want to execute some server side code. BUT I want the user confirmation first, given through a jQuery modal dialog.

Which of the following approaches is correct:

**1)** Put the ASP.Net button (server control who's `OnClick` is linked to the server side event) in the form and use jQuery to open the dialog when clicked:

```
<script ...>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () { return true; },
                'No': function () { return false; }
            }
        });

        $("#<%= SubmitButton.ClientID %>").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div id="ConfirmDialog"></div>
...
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" 
        Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />
```

**2)** Put the ASP.Net Button (server control) in the div used as the confirmation dialog and put a HTML button (non server control) in the form for the user to click.

```
<script ...>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $("#SubmitButton").click(function (event) {
            $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div id="ConfirmDialog">
    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" 
            Text="Yes" OnClick="Submit_Click" />        
    ...
</div>
...
<input id="SubmitButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

I'm going with the first approach but can't make it work, is it ok to do `event.PreventDefault()` and then just `return true;` in the Yes button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd approach is more correct.  If you think about it, you want to use server-side controls when you want some interaction with the server.  In this case, you don't want to interact with the server, but put up a client-side modal dialog, which requires zero interaction with the server to accomplish.

I'd use the following (untested):

```
<script ...>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $("#SubmitButtonClient").click(function (event) {
            $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div id="ConfirmDialog">
    <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" 
            Text="Yes" OnClick="Submit_Click" />        
    ...
</div>
...
<input id="SubmitButtonClient" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

All I changed was the id of the client-side submit button.  In this approach, you don't need to do `event.PreventDefault()`.  Note that I haven't tested the above code.

However, since jQuery is very AJAX-oriented, you generally don't want to do a server postback to accomplish your "button press", but use an AJAX post.  This will prevent the entire page from reloading, and you can adjust your page as needed.  See the [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method in jQuery for some examples.  You'll notice that in ASP.NET MVC you don't see nearly as many server-side controls, but a richer integration with jQuery.  This is the general direction Microsoft is headed - fewer server controls and more AJAX-level integration.